# Background task makes main function and commands not working (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run background task and commands in my discord bot. I've attempted to use `discord.ext.tasks`, but it doesn't work (The problem is same, but the difference is the main function is working). And now I'm trying to use `asyncio` module. So here's my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import dic //This is a module that I made for personal purpose//


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("Login as Discord Bot !")

//Some code for commands here// 

async def time_check():
await client.wait_until_ready()
voice = client.get_channel(int(os.environ['VOICE_CHANNEL']))
text = client.get_channel(int(os.environ['ANNOUNCEMENT']))
while not client.is_closed():
    day = dic.day[datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Singapore")).strftime("%A").lower()]
    now = datetime.strptime(datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Singapore")).strftime("%H:%M"), "%H:%M")
    if day != "tuesday" and day != "saturday":
        times = dic.timing["1"] 
    elif day == "thursday":
        times = dic.timing["2"]
    else:
        times = dic.timing["3"]
    dates = []
    for i in [item.split(" - ") for item in times]:
        for j in i:
                dates.append(j)
    if voice.members is not None:
        if now in dates:
            audio = await voice.connect()
            audio.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("audio.mp3"))
            while audio.is_playing():
                await asyncio.sleep(.1)
            await audio.disconnect()
            if now == timedelta(hours = 9, minutes = 5) or now == timedelta(hours = 9, minutes = 35):
                await text.send(f'Now --> Break')
            else:
                await text.send(f'Now --> {dic.subject[day][int(dates.index(now)/2) + 1]}')
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

client.loop.create_task(time_check())
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

I've seen people uses this method to make a task running in the background. The main function like printing if the bot is online isn't working, and after I deleted `client.loop.create_task(time_check())`, everything works fine. And the main function and commands are working after I deleted the `voice` and `text` too

Comment: What is `dic`?‍

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to add the `dic` module. Actually it's a python file that I created for my purpose

Comment: Not sure about the issue but if you want something to run multiple times and in the background consider using a [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop)

Comment: I've tried it, well the main function is working, but the commands aren't

Comment: I see no issue with the background task, do you maybe have an on_message event? If yes — have you processed commands at the end of it?

Comment: Nope, I don't have an on_message event

Comment: Now, I have more problem, I tried to print members in the voice channel, but it always gave me an empty list